# Fork() execution and number of processes

Tags: unix, process, operating-system

If a process executes the following code

```
fork();
fork();
fork();
```

The total number of child processes created is given as 7 by a text book.
But how does that happen

fork generates 2 processes right? Are both the processes referred to as child processes? One process is the parent parent and one is the child right? 
Even if both the processes are referred to as child processes,2*3=6? The main process is not a child process,how does the number 7 come into the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook is correct. `fork` creates only one child process. `fork` returns PID of the child process in the parent process and 0 in the child.

Below a tree showing this. The numbers show how many forks a process has still to execute. Parenthesis means the process is a parent process, square brackets means the process is a child process - obviously a child process will become a parent in the next generation (next call to `fork`). Each generation is in a separate line.

```
                   (3)
         (2)                   [2]
    (1)      [1]           (1)     [1]
(0)   [0]  (0)  [0]     (0)  [0]  (0)  [0]
```

There is exactly 7 child processes (square brackets).

A Python program to prove it:

```
import os
print os.fork()
print os.fork()
print os.fork()
```

Here is the output. The order is random, but remember, the `fork` returns 0 in the child process:

```
13196
0
13197
13198
0
13199
0
0
13200
13201
0
13202
0
0
```

Comment: @techno Has the answer been helpful? Is there anything still unclear to you?

Comment: sorry for the delay... I have accepted the answer.thanks for your effort.